# Print the name and password saved in array c#

Tags: c#

**So i created this where the data should be saved in an array.** But i tried using print and putting number in array to print it out but it didnt work out. I used Console.WriteLine to print the string saved inside the array but it didn't worked out at all.
Im newbie so help me.

```
public static class Program 
{
   public static void newid() 
   {
    string username = null;
    string passwd = null;

    Usern p = new Usern();
    Console.WriteLine("enter your name:");
    p.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    username = p.Name;

    UserP p1 = new UserP();
    Console.WriteLine("enter password:");
    p1.Password = Console.ReadLine();
    passwd = p1.Password;

   }
    public static void Main() 
    {
       Console.WriteLine("how many account you want to create :");
       int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       int[] numarr = new int[num];

       for (int a = 0; a<num; a++)
       {
        Console.WriteLine("account = {0}",a);
        newid();
       }
       int cc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
       int ddd = numarr;
       Console.WriteLine("{0}");
    }
}
```

Is there any way i can print the data inside the array.

Comment: Are you sure, that your array `num` was not empty while you tested the code?

Comment: wait; what array? the only array there is an array of integers....? side note: in anything even remotely "real", you don't store passwords, ever (unless you're writing password management software, etc, and in that case it is encrypted). But: what are `Usern` and `UserP`? It *seems* like you want a single class `User` with 2 properties, and a `List<User>` ?

Comment: Console.WriteLine(stribg.format("account = {0}",a));

Comment: @GoodSamaritan that will just write the number of accounts; frankly, if you wanted that, `num` would be a better choice than `a`, as it is at least obvious

Comment: This code cannot even be compiled. You cannot assign an array of integers to a single integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a class such as this:

```
class User {
    public string Name;
    public string Password;
}
```

You should then change your newid() to create and return `User` instances.

Finally, you should store the created instances in an array of User: `User[] users = new User[num];`

Try all of this and get back to us.

Answer (score 1):

Here are few pointers that hopefully will help you get a working version.

1. Take pride in your code and respect the user. Use capitalisation and punctuation.

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("How many accounts would you like to create? Please enter a number and press enter:");
   ```
2. Make the array contain a type that stores the username and password. It can be a class or a even a simple tuple.

   ```
   var users = new (string Username, string Passw0rd)[num];
   ```

   (Please note that in a real application passwords are rarely stored in plain text.)
3. Change `newid` to return the data you'll store in the array. For example

   ```
   static (string Name, string Passw0rd) GetAccount()
   {
       string username = null;
       string passwd = null;

       Console.WriteLine("enter your name:");
       username = Console.ReadLine();

       Console.WriteLine("enter password:");
       passwd = Console.ReadLine();

       return( username, passwd );
   }
   ```
4. Call the refactored `newid`/`GetAccount` and store the return value in the array.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i<num; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("account = {0}",i);
       users[i] = GetAccount();
   }
   ```
5. Print the user data

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i<users.Length; i++)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"User {i}");
       Console.WriteLine($"Name: {user[i].Username}");
   }
   ```

Good luck!